# Saving preferences from two classes in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, preferences

I have a problem with Preferences that I wonder if someone can help me with? 
I am working on a game with a settings screen and a game screen. Both needs to be able to write to the same Preferences. The code works in the Settingsscreen, it looks like this:

```
public class SettingsScreen implements Screen{
private Preferences prefs;
    final Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("myprefs");
    prefs.putFloat("volume", volume);
```

and in the Gamescreen I get an error. The code in the Gamescreen looks the same as in settings. This works:

```
volume = prefs.getFloat("volume", 1);
```

but this does not:

```
prefs.putFloat("volume", volume);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mullenuh.learntoread.Screens.GameScreen$4.clicked(GameScreen.java:259)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:353)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:332)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Comment: Need some more code, It's null pointer exception but not clear what is null.

Comment: Is `volume` an Integer object that you forgot to assign a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a local variable called "prefs" in the constructor and member variable also called "prefs" which is still null since you only assign the Preferences instance to the local scope variable.

```
private Preferences prefs; // class member variable
final Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("myprefs"); // local scope variable
```

The reason why this works in your SettingsScreen is probably cause you do the calls on prefs within the local scope.

This is what you probably want:

```
// class member variable
private final Preferences prefs; 
// constructor:    
this.prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("myprefs");
```